# How get rows with oldest date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have table in excel with some columns. There is ID_client and date column, but one client may appear more than once, with different date. My task is to get for all clients rows with the oldest date.

For example, for table:

```
ID_client  date
1          2014-03-01
2          2011-01-06
1          2000-01-15
2          2012-03-16
2          2015-09-26
```

I should receive:

```
ID_client  date
1          2014-03-01
2          2015-09-26
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1:
You can go to *home>Sort & filter> Custom sort*

> select date column>newest to oldest

Step2:Select both column> go to *DATA > Remove duplicates*

> Select only ID column there and hit ok.

You should get the desired output.